# Extract promise type passed as parameter

Tags: typescript, promise, es6-promise

Hi I am trying to achieve this:
if I have a function that gets as a parameter (a promise like as `handleRequest(promise: Promise<any>)` in my example), I want to specify the any type in order to return the correct type and not any.
Here is my try:

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-ives-ougge?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

how can I get the type of variable that the promise passed as a parameter resolves?

edit: As mentioned in the link-
desired result:  x has to get the type of

`[Point,undefined] |[undefined,PromiseError]`
AND
the promise parameter passed to the function handleRequest has to be of type

```
promise: Promise<the type of the passed promise>
```

for example if the passed promise to the function is resolving a number, the promise parameter has to be: `promise: Promise<number>`

Comment: So the link you've added there why doesn't that satisfy what you are looking for here? Since you are passing the type using Generics why not cast it as T at the end?

Comment: I dont want to pass the type, I want it to be extracted from the promise

Comment: @Harry I edited please take a look again

Comment: Please edit the question and include relevant code and desired result

Comment: @AlekseyL. edited for you

Comment: @MD10, i am honestly thinking you are over complicating things here, or you might need to be more specific / clear on what you are trying to achieve. So lets take this step by step first of all whats the point of getting [point, undefined] or [undefined, error] here? the reason am saying this is since you are awaiting you can simply throw the exception and catch it

Comment: I want to wrap my requests so I dont have to write try catch every time
The purpose of the desired type is to get intellisense on the returned result

Comment: I've simplified the question for you https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwAowPYFsCWyIAojNjPAN4C+AUHgHYAuIMAZlGAulg45TfHgAPAFzx6AVxwAjFgG4B8AJ5jJM+TVo1QSOIiz1kfURh5MA2gF14AHwzZ8hEmSsKwBo8vgBeYeYAMlnLwAPQh9rgExKRY5AxGIFDA8Fispry2EY7RZDRAA The question here why we loose the `Point` after destructuring. And the answer is: because `PromiseError` is currently structurally compatible with **anything**. Just add some props to it `declare class PromiseError { message: string }`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Have you understood my goal ? can you change the code in sandbox to fulfill the desired result please ?

Comment: Sure, I thought you would like to know why it is not working... Here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/white-cloud-31qpz?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks for the reply, Can you please explain me what as const here does? why without it ,it doesn't work?

Comment: It prevents return type widening to array and makes typescript to infer it as read-only tuple. So at index 0 we can get data or undefined and at index 1 error or undefined. I think this is what you were looking for. You could of course define function's return type explicitly instead

Comment: what does it mean  type widening? I don't get it.. why if I dont put the 'as const' I get the last type?

Comment: You'll get an array instead of tuple. Have a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

Comment: So if I understood correctly, this const assertion has be to relted with the fact that I want to tell explicitly that the return type is a tuple with data,undefined and  undefined,error and not the general tye of array that is coomon to both try and catch? If so, why without this, TypeScript cant understand that I can return from the function only [data, undefined] or [undefined,error]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try modifying your `handleRequest` as following:

```js
const handleRequest = <T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<[T | PromiseError, undefined]> => {
    return promise
        .then((data): [T, undefined] => [data, undefined])
        .catch((error): [PromiseError, undefined] => [error, undefined]);
};
```

Using your example code above, the result variable would be of type `[PromiseError | Point, undefined]`:

```
const x = await handleRequest(p()); //  [PromiseError | Point, undefined]
```